# Trying to import images in react but getting cant resolve error

Tags: reactjs, image, import

I'm trying to import images in react, i've searched tons of answer and videos but just cant seem to get mine working.

Here's my directory:
[image]

Here's my code

```
import React from 'react';
import './header.css'
import people from '../assets/people.png';
```

and the error im getting is

```
ERROR in ./src/containers/header/header.jsx 6:0-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/people.png' in 'C:\Users\ojadi\gpt3_jsm\src\containers\header'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need in your import is two levels, you're imported one `../assets`

```
import '../../assets/people.png';
```

Answer (score 2):

You're importing one level too shallow.

It should be:

```
import people from '../../assets/people.png';
```